# jmeter variable can not be referenced as expected

Tags: regex, variables, scope, jmeter, extractor

I have a problem with my Test Plan. If I add User Defined Variable, let's say csrftoken and assign NOT_INITIALIZED to it in User Defined Variables config element, it is passed to http request where it is referenced, but not set in prior http request sampler that has a regular expression extractor child element, that is supposed to set it, which means it is passed as "NOT_INITIALIZED". If I don't use User Defined Variables config element to declare it, I cannot reference it in later http request, that is, it stays like ${csrftoken}, although it "should be" set/created by previous http request and its post processing regexp Extractor, since it properly references the name. I think, there might be some problem with the scope, but I can't figure what. Everything is within the same Transaction Controller, nothing changes if I place everything directly at the Thread Group level. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to initialize a variable, Regular Expression Extractor can create a variable and assign a value to it on its own.

If variable value isn't getting substituted - something is wrong with regex or template. If you could update your question with the relevant response bit and your Regular Expression Extractor configuration community and myself would be able to assist.

Few references:

- You can test your regular expressions against response data right in [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener by choosing RegExp Tester option from the dropdown

  [image: Regex Tester]
- Sometimes it isn't handy to use Regular Expressions for parsing HTML as they may be complex, markup-dependent and fragile so it's better to consider [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) or [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) instead.
- See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) guide for comprehensive information on how to bypass CSRF protection in your JMeter test.

Comment: Hi, I think the problem is in the order of execution. The http request sampler that is supposed to extract the value from the response is processed after the one that is supposed to use the value, that is in reversed order from the one I expected by reading this: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html

Comment: The reason for this, I think, is that I don't understand quite following redirects within jmeter. I used "Follow redirects" during recording, and all recorded http request samplers have following redirects checked, when I replay them. Is this actually duplicating redirected requests?

Comment: So, I have a post http request, which is redirected to a get http request, and from its response data I am supposed to extract a csrf value. Whatever I try, I can't seem to make it work. I added Debug post processor, besides regexp extractor post processor to the same http request sampler, but I don't see the result of its processing in a View Result Tree. Does anyone have a link to a document that explains how to extract data from redirected response?

Comment: Well, I added a User Defined Variable config element and a a Debug sampler just to confirm the http request sampler that I tried to use for extracting a value, actually doesn't get executed. Than I realized that I can extract the value from the previous (post) http requst sampler. So I solved that, csrftoken is now referenced properly by the following http request. However, that is not enough. I have to extract another value to another variable, from the same Response data in order not to get tampering exception. So I added another regexp extractor which is supposed to create the new variable.

Comment: But the variable doesn't get created. Not to mention that although both strings that I intend to match by regular expressions appear in recorded response data, when I replay the test, only csrf appears in response. So even, if I could manage to make the second extractor work, I don't know from where will it be possible to extract needed data.

Comment: Actually, I made the second extractor work by adding NOT_FOUND as a default value for it, which is what I finally get, since there is no match in response data for the post http request. Now, I have to figure out from where to extract the second string. In recorded scenario, both strings are present in the response of the redirected (get) http request. In replayed scenario, only csrf is present in response of post http request, and I removed the get http request, since it doesn't get executed.

Comment: I think this is too much for me without help from the community. I think I'm gonna drop the whole jmeter effort and try something else.

Comment: I have solved my problem by enabling all disabled http request samplers (results of redirects during recording, which I have done with "follow redirects" checked), unticking all "follow redirects" on all produced http request samplers (results of redirects or not), and by applying needed correlation on recorded scenario. Of course, if I was an experienced jmeter user, I would realize without using Debug samplers  that some of produced http request samplers were disabled, On the other hand, in that case I probably wouldn't write here asking for answers to my questions. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Applying needed (session & csrf) correlation seems to me like a more or less trivial task that shouldn't be performed manually. Does anyone know how to perform it automatically? I thought regex matching option in HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder is provided for that purpose to assist with that, but I guess I was wrong?

Comment: JMeter doesn't provide auto-correlation option yet, as far as I know LoadRunner does, if your budget allows - consider switching to it. Personally I don't use recorder and develop scripts manually using Wireshark sniffer tool

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. Following your advice, I investigated XPath Extractor, and realized that it potentially offers a way towards semiautomatic correlation, by using for example Firebug. I mean, it still is manual correlation, but at least you don't have to actually write XPath  expressions manually.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answering. I think regular expression extractor is OK:

```
Apply To:                Main sample and sub samples
Field to check:          Body
Reference Name:          csrftoken
Regular Expression:      csrfToken = '(.+?)';
Template:                $1$
Match No.(0 for Random): 1
Default Value:
```

it gives 4 matches on Response data, when I use RegExp tester from View Results Tree, for example:

```
Match count: 4
Match[1][0]=csrfToken = 'Wp6jXFdyUkJmJaJq_MVwH-rKnI7jwXHEtwxLoddUBHLzyT4*';
Match[1][1]=Wp6jXFdyUkJmJaJq_MVwH-rKnI7jwXHEtwxLoddUBHLzyT4*
Match[2][0]=csrfToken = 'Wp6jXFdyUkJmJaJq_MVwH-rKnI7jwXHEtwxLoddUBHLzyT4*';
Match[2][1]=Wp6jXFdyUkJmJaJq_MVwH-rKnI7jwXHEtwxLoddUBHLzyT4*
Match[3][0]=csrfToken = 'Wp6jXFdyUkJmJaJq_MVwH-rKnI7jwXHEtwxLoddUBHLzyT4*';
Match[3][1]=Wp6jXFdyUkJmJaJq_MVwH-rKnI7jwXHEtwxLoddUBHLzyT4*
Match[4][0]=csrfToken = 'Wp6jXFdyUkJmJaJq_MVwH-rKnI7jwXHEtwxLoddUBHLzyT4*';
Match[4][1]=Wp6jXFdyUkJmJaJq_MVwH-rKnI7jwXHEtwxLoddUBHLzyT4*
```

Shall I rather post the excerpts from jmx here?